# this.id not working in ie

Tags: javascript, onclick

I've been putting together an accordion-style left-navigation using JavaScript, and I've run into a problem where the following code works in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE.

```
function navClick(clickedDD){
    var numDD = document.getElementsByClassName('navDropdown');
    var numArrow = document.getElementsByClassName('navUnfolded');
    var selectedDD = document.getElementById('dd0' + clickedDD);
    var arrow = document.getElementById('arrow0' + clickedDD);
    if (selectedDD.style.display == 'none') {
        for (var i = numDD.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            numDD[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    if (arrow.className == 'navFolded') {
        for (var i = numArrow.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            numArrow[i].className = 'navFolded';
        }
    }
    if (selectedDD.style.display == 'none') {
        selectedDD.style.display = 'block';
        arrow.className = 'navUnfolded';
    } else {
        selectedDD.style.display = 'none';
        arrow.className = 'navFolded';
    }
}
```

I'm not positive what's keeping it from functioning, but I suspect it's the "this.id" I'm using in the onclick.

```
<div id="1" onclick="navClick(this.id);">Content</div>
```

I'm relatively new to JavaScript, if that's helpful to know. Basically, this function first looks to see if the clicked div is displayed or not, and if not then it sets display to none for all the divs before continuing. If it is displayed, it does nothing because the next bit will handle it. There's a similar rule right after for divs with an arrow image that changes. Then if it the div is not displayed, it sets it to 'block' or else it sets it to 'none', which allows me to open and close a single menu div without opening/closing the others.

I'm using the id collected by the onclick function to control a div with a different id, as can be seen in the bottom to variables at the top of the function. Perhaps this is where IE is getting touchy.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a console to read errors?

Comment: are html attribute values strings? should it be `id="1"`?

Comment: Check what will happen if you'll use quotes for `id` value:

`<div id="1" onclick="navClick(this.id);">Content</div>`

Comment: My bad, I don't actually have the id defined there, but another javascript function adds the id value. I put it like this here for easier reference.

Comment: The console tells me "Object doesn't support this property or method" in reference to my var numDD. Does IE not handle getElementsByClassName?

Comment: Try adding `console.log(typeof clickedDD)` after your function definition. This will tell you if it is undefined, which would be the problem. Also, have you considered jQuery? It is a lot easier to use, saves time and is cross-browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` [isn't supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=getelementsbyclassname) in IE8 or below.

You could try [Jonathan Snook's](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/your_favourite_1) approach for IE8 and below compatibility if you don't want to use a full library.

Comment: Excellent. This was the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

On your  element, try puttin the ID in quotes:

```
<div id = '1' onClick="navClick(this.id);">
```

You could also try using javascript's 'Alert' function to find out what the data looks like in IE:

```
alert(selectedDD);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your id in `<div id="1" ..` is not a valid one:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

so try changing it for valid one (eg. `#a1`) as that may be the cause of your problem.

Comment: This is true but all the emulated versions of IE seems to work fine with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/FYVjh/).